# ESP32 print weird data on Arduino IDE Serial Monitor

Tags: esp32, serial-data

I tried to upload a sketch on esp32 devkit v1 (wroom) picture of my board is below :

[image]

but this message is always printed on the serial monitor continuously and quickly :

rst:0x3 (SW_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:1
load:0x3fff0018,len:4
load:0x3fff001c,len:1216
ho 0 tail 12 room 4
load:0x40078000,len:10944
load:0x40080400,len:6388
entry 0x400806b4
ets Jun  8 2016 00:22:57

I tried multiple sketches and all of them successfully uploaded but always got same data printing in serial monitor as output

In the beginning, the shield on the board heats up a little, but after I made the following settings, it no longer heats up (i powered my board only by connecting it by simple USB cable from my laptop USB port) :

Board : ESP32 Dev Module

Upload Speed :115200

CPU Frequency : "240MHz(wifi/BT)

Flash Frequency : 80MHz

Flash Mode : QIO

Flash Size : 16MB(128Mb)

Partition Scheme : 16M Flash(3MB APP/9MB FATFS)

Core Debug Level : None

PSRAM : Enabled

Arduino IDE version : 1.8.9

ESP Core version : by Espressif Systems version 1.0.6

Is my board burnt due to the setting for maximum performance, and I shouldn't have made these settings for this board?  To adjust these parameters in a way that does not damage the board, how much should I adjust each parameter?

Any suggestions to fix it?

(Nothing connected to GPIO pins and also nothing connected to wifi & Bluetooth)

UPDATE :

If I set the board settings to default, the program will upload to the esp32 board, but I want to use the maximum performance of my board, so how high can I increase each setting?
(settings like cpu freq. Flash freq. and etc. )
How can i be sure of this?
Is there any sketch & instructions to find out how high can i select them?(it seems the board isn't Original and I'm not sure about it's specifications, how can i get this information by any sketch from it and then how high can i set the setting? )

Comment: Have you tried an empty sketch with nothing connected to the ESP32?

Comment: Is it possible to upload empty sketch on it? ( nothing connected to the board at all - answer deited by mentioning this)

Comment: an empty sketch is a sketch with only the functions `setup()` and `loop()` without anything in them

Comment: I know, i tried now and successfully uploaded but got same result

Comment: It seems this error can have many reasons. How are you powering the ESP? Do you use the latest ESP32 core in the Arduino IDE? What are your board settings when programming?

Comment: The question updated by the info you want (thanks for your help)

Comment: This looks like a very standard ESP32 Dev board, which usually have only 4MB of Flash and no PSRAM. Change the settings for "Flash Size" to 4MB, change the PSRAM setting to "disabled" and try again. You are also working with an old Arduino IDE version and ESP32 Core version.

Comment: What is the rest of setting? Are they right? (Frequencies, partition Scheme, ... ). do those settings work for this board?

Comment: setting changes done, still same problem

Comment: set 40MHz for the flash

Comment: *"ESP Core version : by Espressif Systems version 1.0.6"*  This seems to be latest the 1.x line, but we're up to 2.0.5 now overall. You may want to try with the current core. The IDE is also a little outdated, but if either make any difference at all, it would probably be the core version. May not matter at all, but it's an easy test and odds are anyone trying to help is on the newer core anyway.

Comment: I found the an issue . The question updated by new info. Check it out

Comment: if your flash memory chip can handle only 40 MHz then you can't set 80 MHz. if is connected as DIO then you can't set QIO. if the module has a 4 MB flash, you can't set 16 MB in Tools menu

Comment: The main question is, the board it's not Original and how can i be sure of these? And then what is the detailed instructions to set these board settings?

Comment: Simply use the defaults as they are usually fine. If your board runs with the defaults, you can try to change a setting and see if it has any effect. There usually is not much to gain performance wise. You can find out what most settings do by searching for them or looking them up in the ESP32 data sheet. For example [here is a discussion about Flash modes](https://www.esp32.com/viewtopic.php?t=1250) which may be interesting.